# Why systemctl services are loaded but failed CentOS 7

Tags: linux, openstack, centos7

I finished to install Openstack Magnum service on CentOS 7, using this guide: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/magnum/install-guide-from-source.html

Checking the magnum-api and magnum-conductor services after reboot shows that the services are active, but few seconds later they are in failed state. The selinux is disabled, and the services are enabled.

Restarting the magnum api service:

```
[root@controller01 magnum]# systemctl restart magnum-api
```

magnum-api status OK:

```
[root@controller01 magnum]# systemctl status magnum-api
● magnum-api.service - OpenStack Magnum API Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/magnum-api.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-11-08 09:50:01 IST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 21705 (magnum-api)
   CGroup: /system.slice/magnum-api.service
           └─21705 /var/lib/magnum/env/bin/python /var/lib/magnum/env/bin/magnum-api

Nov 08 09:50:01 controller01 systemd[1]: Started OpenStack Magnum API Service.
Nov 08 09:50:01 controller01 systemd[1]: Starting OpenStack Magnum API Service...
```

magnum-api service is failed after few seconds:

```
[root@controller01 magnum]# systemctl status magnum-api
    ● magnum-api.service - OpenStack Magnum API Service
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/magnum-api.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2016-11-08 09:50:03 IST; 6s ago
      Process: 21705 ExecStart=/var/lib/magnum/env/bin/magnum-api (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 21705 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Nov 08 09:50:02 controller01 systemd[1]: magnum-api.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Nov 08 09:50:02 controller01 systemd[1]: Unit magnum-api.service entered failed state.
    Nov 08 09:50:02 controller01 systemd[1]: magnum-api.service failed.
    Nov 08 09:50:03 controller01 systemd[1]: magnum-api.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
    Nov 08 09:50:03 controller01 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for magnum-api.service
    Nov 08 09:50:03 controller01 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenStack Magnum API Service.
    Nov 08 09:50:03 controller01 systemd[1]: Unit magnum-api.service entered failed state.
    Nov 08 09:50:03 controller01 systemd[1]: magnum-api.service failed.
```

Happens the same for the magnum-conductor service.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Dedi

Comment: This isn't a programming question - you would have better luck asking on superuser, or one of the other se sites. That said; there should be service specific logs you can look at (possibly in `/var/log/magnum` ?)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Petesh. I just figure it out. The issue was because I set in the magnum.conf file:
`host = controller`.
Once I replaced the "controller" with the ip, it works. In other words, set:
`host = <controller_IP>`.